# MySQL throwing an exception when creating a table, but only in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have been working with MySQL for some time now, and for some odd reason, whether in be some NPE in my code that I don't see, or just me mistyping, I am getting errors that I have not before

```
static MySQL sql = Essentials.getinstance().sql;
    public static String TABLE_MAIN = "`PlayerStats`";
    public static String TABLE_GROUP = "`Groups`";
    public static String TABLE_BUILDNG = "`Build`";
    public static String TABLE_ARCHERY = "`Archer`";
    public static String TABLE_DIGGING = "`Dig`";
    public static String TABLE_MINING = "`Mine`";
    public static String TABLE_FARMING = "`Farm`";
    public static String TABLE_WOODCUTTIN = "`Wood`";
    public static String TABLE_FIGHTING = "`Combat`";
    public static String KEY = "`Player`";
    public static String LEVEL = "`Level`";
    public static String XP = "`XP`";
    public static String[] tables = new String[] { TABLE_MAIN, TABLE_ARCHERY, TABLE_BUILDNG, TABLE_DIGGING, TABLE_FARMING, TABLE_FIGHTING, TABLE_MINING, TABLE_WOODCUTTIN };

public PlayerStats() {
this.start();
this.setName("RPG-Setup");
}

@Override
public void run() {
for(String table : tables){
    sql.updateSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table + "(" + KEY + " varchar(128), " + LEVEL + " bigint, " + XP + " bigint, PRIMARY KEY(" + KEY + "))");
}
sql.updateSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `Groups` (`Player` varchar(128), `Group` varchar(64), PRIMARY KEY(`Player`))");
}
```

The entire class is much longer, but this is what is throwing the error:

```
sql.updateSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `Groups` (`Player` varchar(128), `Group` varchar(64), PRIMARY KEY(`Player`))");
```

What makes no sense is why. It's not throwing an NPE, but instead it throws this:

```
[19:55:42 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQ
L server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No comment about the problem, but naming a column `Group` is a bad, bad, bad idea.  That is a reserved word in all databases.   Use your imagination and come up with a better name.

Comment: It's not "bad, bad, bad idea". It's just "bad idea". And you need to understand what are you doing, because you can have column named `group` w/o much problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use Group as a column name, which is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I put this into a MySQL editor and it had no problem. If memory serves me right, as long as you denote a value with "``" you should be fine. I'll test this anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part somehow that you actually quoted them in ``.

Comment: I've just tried to run your statement without `` quotation on my MySQL instance, and the result was:
`mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Groups (Player varchar(128), Group varchar(64), PRIMARY KEY(Player));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group varchar(64), PRIMARY KEY(Player))' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here the SQL Syntax all seems to be correct. But in your code to declare the tables string may be a problem not sure.

Instead of the below code

String[] tables = new String[] { TABLE_MAIN, TABLE_ARCHERY, TABLE_BUILDNG, TABLE_DIGGING, TABLE_FARMING, TABLE_FIGHTING, TABLE_MINING, TABLE_WOODCUTTIN };

You can try this..

String[] tables ={ TABLE_MAIN, TABLE_ARCHERY, TABLE_BUILDNG, TABLE_DIGGING, TABLE_FARMING, TABLE_FIGHTING, TABLE_MINING, TABLE_WOODCUTTIN };

OR Use List to define the tables ..It may ensure you the problem is not in the SQL.